# Jmeter Exceptions

Tags: jmeter

Hi please elaborate following exceptions:

```
Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketTimeoutException
Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
Non HTTP response code: org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException
Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException
```

Comment: Request has timed out from server side. check server side transaction/request time outs. If possible increase/double them and check again. This should resolve the error.

Comment: Hi Nachiket,Will you elaborate each exception in brief for the above.

Comment: java.net.SocketTimeoutException exception is what is suggests. Socket connection timed out. it means your request has timed out from server side. this depends on request timeouts configuration present on server side.